# Send data between more than two Android devices with Wi-Fi Direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have successfully connected two devices with Wi-Fi Direct in Android as well as passing data between them.

My test application is roughly based on the source code from the Wi-Fi Direct Service Discovery example (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectServiceDiscovery)

When the application starts, I can see all my three devices in the list of possible device that can be connected (Samsung Galaxy S2, Samsung Galaxy S4 and Google Nexus 7 are used for tests).

If I connect from my S2 to my S4, they can communicate with no problems.
If I then try to connect my Nexus 7, it can connect to my S2 (the S4 is no longer available) it can communicate with the S2, but the data cannot be see from the S4, nor data that's send between the S2 and S4 can be seen from the Nexus 7.

I have tried to elaborate with changing the groupOwnerIntent during the connect:

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
config.deviceAddress = service.device.deviceAddress;
config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
config.groupOwnerIntent = 0; // 0 for first connect/groupOwner and 15 otherwise
```

Unfortunately, when changing the groupOwnerIntent, the communication does no longer work, not even between two devices.

Has anyone got this to work and can give any hints about how this can be solved?